# Getting numbers behind decimal separator

Tags: c, if-statement, decimal

I'm trying to get numbers behind decimal point and use them in another statement.

for example:

```
int input1;
float x;
if (input1 >= 500)
{
    x = input1 / 500
}
```

if `input1 == 1700` then `x` would be `3.4`. Now I only need .4 to work with it in the next statement. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Lundin How is this question same as the one marked as duplicate?

Comment: First find remainder using `x = input1 % 500` and then divide result by 500 as `x = x/500`. This will do the trick.

Comment: it's not same question....

Comment: What result do you want when `input1 == -1700`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = (input1 % 500) * 1.0f / 500
```

`input1 % 500` will take just the remainder of the number and skip the quotient part. Multiplication with `1.0f` will convert the number into float and further division with `500` (or better `500.0f`) will give you the floating point number.